# Accessing List<Class> elements in Java

Tags: java, list, jpa, collections

Please ignore any beginner mistakes if I make. Following is my issue:

I have a class Item :

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
//@ManyToOne
private Long id;
private String stream_item_key;
private String stream_item_date;
private String channel;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "item_workflow", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Workflow> workflow;
```

Workflow is another class and Workflow has the following class members:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String actor;
    private String assignee;
    private String date;
    private String team;
    private String action;
```

I have used JPA to join item and workflow and I am able to see the complete extract of the data. However in a different method I am trying to extract only `Item.stream_item_date, Workflow.Actor and Workflow.date`

I am able to extract `Item.stream_item_date` using the `getStream_item_date()` accessor but I am not sure how to access the List elements. I have researched Stackoverflow and I could not find any answers, all of them led to update index and other things. I am not sure if this is the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to achieve? Are you asking about how to write a JPQL query? About how to iterate on a List?

Comment: How to iterate on the List and retrieve List elements.

Comment: `for (Workflow workflow: item.workflows) { ... }`. Why are you using such complex frameworks as JPA if you don't know how to write loops yet? Learn the basic stuff first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer [@JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)

```
Item items = this.getQueryOne(); 
// getQueryOne() returns the Item object
for (Workflow workflow: items.getWorkflow()) {
   System.out.println(workflow.getActor());
   System.out.println(workflow.getDate());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   for(Iterator<?>ui=Item.getWorkflow().iterator()ui.hasNext();‌​){ 
         Workflow temp= (Workflow) ui.next(); 
           System.out.print(temp.getActor()); }
```

Comment: for(Iterator<?>ui=Item.getWorkflow().iterator()ui.hasNext();){
   Workflow temp= (Workflow) ui.next();
   System.out.print(temp.getActor());
   }

Comment: or you can try the one in my comment. since you are using many to many. The one I answered was to give you an idea to access the list elements. but the one in my comment will be more reliable for your case. Hope it could be a help.

Comment: @lucky123 you just need to use iterator when you want to access what's inside the list. check the one in my comment it could be much more of a help

Comment: Your answer makes no sense. Edit your answer to fix it, instead of adding comments. Note that the foreach loop exists since Java 5.